# T-SQL/XML Query to get for each row in the query a subfield as well as the whole lement

Tags: sql, xml

I have an XML string like this:

```
<Root>
  <Elem>
    <RecTime>2016-08-17 12:30PM</RecTime>
    <Otherfield>blah blah</Otherfield>
    .. other fields ..
  </Elem>
  <Elem>
    <RecTime>2016-08-17 15:30PM</RecTime>
    <Otherfield>more blah</Otherfield>
    .. other fields ..
  </Elem>
</Root>
```

Obviously this describes a list of elements. I want to extract the record time as well as the entire element for every element in the XML - this is because I want to insert in a table the record time as well as the entire element: the table could be declared as

```
DECLARE Table myTable(SampleTime datetime, Data xml)
```

I tried the query

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml='<Root>
<Elem>
    <RecordTime>2016-08-17 12:30:00PM</RecordTime>
    <Otherfield>2</Otherfield>
    <field2/>
</Elem>
<Elem>
    <RecordTime>2016-08-17 15:30:00PM</RecordTime>
    <Otherfield>3</Otherfield>
    <field2>hello there</field2>
</Elem>
</Root>'

--INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT SampleTime = T.Item.value('RecordTime[1]', 'dateTime'),
            Data = @xml.query('//Root/Elem[1]')
        FROM @xml.nodes('//Root/Elem') T(item)
```

but it gives me rows that contain the proper time for each row but only the first element in the list for the 'whole element' part of the query:
[image]

I circled in red the proof that I select the wrong element
How should I shape the query to get in response the sample time for each element as well as the corresponding element?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good question! +1 from my side. You stated the problem clearly, there is a MCVE, own effort, wrong output and a clear explanation what should be there (expected output). And everything is copy'n'pasteable! Great!

Comment: Only one tiny hint: You should not start your XPath with a double slash `//Root/Elem`. This would search for any Element with the name "Root" anywhere in the XML. In your case this might be of no impact, but this might lead to strange results and very heavy debugging...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in `Data = @xml.query('//Root/Elem[1]')`. To achieve what you want use something like this.

```
--INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT SampleTime = T.Item.value('RecordTime[1]', 'dateTime'),
            Data = T.item.query('.')
        FROM @xml.nodes('Root/Elem') T(item) --No // before Root. Thanks to Shnugo
```

This is result.

```
2016-08-17 12:30:00.000 <Elem><RecordTime>2016-08-17 12:30:00PM</RecordTime><Otherfield>2</Otherfield><field2 /></Elem>
2016-08-17 15:30:00.000 <Elem><RecordTime>2016-08-17 15:30:00PM</RecordTime><Otherfield>3</Otherfield><field2>hello there</field2></Elem>
```

Comment: This gives me ALL elements in the input xml. I want only the element corresponding to the sample time I extracted with "SampleTime = T.Item.value('RecordTime[1]', 'dateTime')", which is the sample time for each element.Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, Good answer (+1 from my side), but you might read the hint I posted below the question...

Comment: @Shnugo I copied it from OP and just forget to look at the last line. ;D. Fixed.